# How to call a azure function that works on localhost and return 500 on azure portal?

Tags: python, azure-functions

I have a Azure Function created in VSCode with Python. The API contain the access to a AzureWebJob, when I tested it in the local host http://localhost:7071/api/FUNCTIONNAME?Param1=value1 the response is 200 and the JSON return is ok but, when I deploy the function to Azure the link https://APPSERVICENAME.azurewebsites.net/api/FUNCTIONNAME?code=APICODE==&Param1=value1 return 500 Internal Server Error.

I'm using Postman to test and replied the query on Chrome.

The code used is:

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime as dt
import json

#filter the dataframe
def filter(pdf, keys, daterange):
  jkeys=[]
  for key in keys:
    #filter by numeric key
    if(reg.isdigit()):
      jkeys.append(int(key))
  #filtering by two types of keys
  pdfA=pdf[pdf['key'].isin(keys)]
  pdfS=pdf[pdf['numerickey'].isin(jkeys)]
  #concat the DFs
  pdf=pd.concat([pdfS,pdfA],axis=0)
  #Filtering by a dateRange or single date
  if(daterange.isdigit()): 
    pdf=pdf[pdf['Day']==int(daterange)]
    return pdf
  else:
    #getting the two dates
    date=daterange.split('-')
    #filtering the rows
    pdf=pdf[(pdf['Day']>=int(date[0])) & (pdf['Day']<=int(date[1]))]
    return pdf

# function to validate the params
def param_validation(param: str,
                    param_name: str,
                    req: func.HttpRequest) -> str:
                    
    if not param:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:

            if param != None and '-' in param:
                return func.HttpResponse(
                    "Set a date in the query",
                    status_code=400
                )
        else:
            param = req_body.get(param_name)
            return param
    else:
        return param

def main(req: func.HttpRequest,
            inputBlob: func.InputStream) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    #get the params
    daterange = req.params.get('daterange')
    keys = req.params.get('keys')
    name=req.params.get('name')

    daterange = param_validation(daterange, 'daterange', req)
    keys = param_validation(keys, 'keys', req)

    #this condition is included just to test fast if works 
    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello {name}!")
    #This is to get the real data request function
    if daterange and (keys):
        try:
            
            if daterange and keys:
                # get the data from a csv in the datalake 
                data = pd.read_csv(StringIO(inputBlob.read().decode('utf-8')))
                keys=keys.split(',')  
                dfFilt=filter(data,keys,daterange).fillna(0)

                return func.HttpResponse(f"{json.dumps(dfFilt.to_dict(orient='record'))}")

            else:
                return func.HttpResponse(
                    "insert a valid daterange to the query",
                    status_code=400
            )
        except:
                return func.HttpResponse(
                    "Params are wrong.",
                    status_code=500
            )
    else:
            return func.HttpResponse(
                "Params missed",
                status_code=400
            )
```

The purpose is to get a csv from datalake and return the rows filtered by 2 args provided.

I found more information about the error, the platform return a **137 python code**. I deployed the last functional api with a stale csv (that is lighter, 60mb) and the api works good. But when I a set the new csv (300mb) the api starts to return the code 500 internal server error.

I think that is just this memory problem, because in the local host works perfectly.

are another way to get the data from datalake, filtering two columns using a azure function? Or its posible to fix this memory problem ?

Thanks!

Comment: API Code? Do you give it the key?

Comment: Hi, any update?

Comment: Yes, I added the python error and the code implemented.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can caused by many reasons, so please show more details. On my side, it is no problem.

1, the param code should be the key of your function(if it is not anonymous.)

2, please check your code, maybe you are using something that is not exists.(So please show your code and other files.)

You can use application Insights to check the details error or you can directly go to see the log files:

Go to `https://yourfunctionappname.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`, and then click to `LogFiles\Application\Functions\Function\HttpTrigger1>`, you will find the log files there, click in and check the error.

Any update please let me know.

Comment: I  updated the info about the error!  If you know how to solve that,  please let me know.  I keep working on that, if I found the way  to solve it. I will post the solution.